# How to make an object injected by spring managed in a JPA context?

Tags: java, spring, jpa

In my controller I receive an User of SpringContext thats represent the author of the book and pass to create a book because they have an jpa relation, but in a JPA context this User is detached and I need to make it managed before to save a Book.

```
@Autowired @Lazy
private User loggedUser;

@PostMapping
public String createNewBook(newBookForm form) {
     Book book = newBookForm.toBook(loggedUser);
     bookRepository.save(book);

     return "redirect:home";
}
```

I had thought of two ways, one using my UserRepository to get a new User using logged.getId():

```
User user = userRepository.getOne(loggedUser.getId());
```

Or inject an EntityManager and work out of Spring Data Jpa.

Then I want to know if that's a best approach between both or another way... but but of the two above I prefer the first.

Comment: CrudRepository is the best approach.

Comment: @User-Upvotedon'tsayThanks For me too, but I thing its strange to get another User because I really have one